# custom setter for double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) double lastSynced;

and here's my custom setter:

-(void)setLastSynced:(double)newLastSynced
{
    if (lastSynced != newLastSynced){
        lastSynced = newLastSynced;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:lastSynced forKey:kSettingLastSyncedKey];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

I am not sure why my custom setter is not called when I am setting the lastSynced? I have it synthesized as

> @synthesized lastSynced.

Comment: try removing @synthesize and adding a getter method(`-(double)getLastSynced {    return lastSynced;  }`

Comment: @Novarg: then there would be no ivar. It's valid to replace only one or the other (or both!) accessor method even when synthesizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly declaring your setter?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, setter=setLastSynched:) double lastSynced;
```

Answer (score -1):

It is very bad that in synthesized you are not writeing lastSynced = _lastSynced when you're creating custom setter because inside setter you are trying to call your setter.
Try to :

```
@synthesize lastSynced = _lastSynced

-(void)setLastSynced:(double)newLastSynced
{
         if (_lastSynced != newLastSynced)
    {
            _lastSynced = newLastSynced;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:_lastSynced  forKey:kSettingLastSyncedKey];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: The setter isn't being using inside itself. Where are you getting that idea from?